# Remove &nbsp in span

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<span class="wprevpro_star_imgs_T1"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/thefinancialhub105706898.wpcomstaging.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-places-review-slider/public/partials/imgs/stars_5_yellow.png?w=1110&amp;ssl=1" alt="5 star review" class="wprevpro_t1_star_img_file" width="100" height="19">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

I want to remove the double &nbsp at the end of my span with a css code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Nor with CSS you can't, No.

Comment: You can't get content like that text actually changed with CSS you'd need Javascript, is that acceptable. Is removing the characters actually what is needed, or do you want to remove/reuse the space they occupy in some way?

Comment: I would imagine the easiest way is to look at the back-end, the template, or the component... that introduces those non-breaking spaces and prevent their insertion; though that's obviously beyond the scope of the answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "remove" it from your HTML with styling. What might be enough for your case is *hiding* that text instead, preventing its selection like in the picture below.

[image: nbsp is selected].

One possible way to get there is simply setting font-size to 0:

```
.wprevpro_star_imgs_T1 {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A span tag acts like an inline element so you are using a `&nbsp;` But you can make in an inline Block and solve the problem by two methods:

- by using Margin Right;

```css
.wprevpro_star_imgs_T1{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

- by using Padding Right;

```css
.wprevpro_star_imgs_T1{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to solve this issue.

You can remove (ctrl+h) find    and replace nothing then press replace all.

2nd. Using jQuery:

```
<script>
var span = $('span').html();
span = span.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
$('span').html(span);
</script>
```

3rd.

```
<script>
var span = $('span').html();
span = span.replace('&nbsp;','');
$('span').html(span);
</script>
```

CSS is possible? it's out of my mind.